# Finding if there is big divergence in current values of two variables X& Y wrt their historical values

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, correlation, divergence-operator

I have two variables X and Y.

I have historical data about X and Y.

I have quantified correlation between X and Y

My Question is : Given current value for X(= x_current) and Y(=y_current) AND I want to quantify how divergent current (x_current, y_current) value is from  historical correlation value between X and Y. How this is solved in practical applications ?

Note: This is not academic question. I am professional and forgotten many of these things taught to me at school and don't even remember technical terms used for defining these questions.

Can u please answer or point to appropriate resource for further research ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little short on details (e.g. are $x_{current}$ or $y_{current}$ single values or sets?), but I'll give two suggestions for what you could do.

1. A statistical approach would be to compare the correlation in a set of old data to that of a set of new ("current") data, using the [Fisher transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation) ("r-to-z") to do significance testing.
2. Since you tag with `machine-learning`, you might want to consider using machine learning-based outlier detection approaches (e.g. see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#id1)). Basically, you learn a model for the historical data, and then ask it whether the *current* data is abnormal (a measure which can be quantified), given that model. This is not specifically for correlations though, I suppose.